# Angular Full Calendar For add ng-Bootstrap modal popup

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, ng-bootstrap

I'm used my university project for Angular Full Calendar , I want t o know how to added Calendar event for Modal popup look my image , calendar is working good, but I don't know how to add  Modal popup for this event,

please help me this?
Thanks
[image]

I want to know how to add that event to [ng-bootstrap-Modal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)

This is my code ,

**index.component.ts**

```
export class IndexComponent {

 calendarOptions:Object = {
height: 'parent',
fixedWeekCount : false,
defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
editable: true,
eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

events: [
  {
    title: 'All Day Event',
    start: '2016-09-01'
  },

  {
    id: 999,
    title: 'Repeating Event',
    start: '2016-09-09T16:00:00'
  },
  }
```

**index.component.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="calendar">
    <angular2-fullcalendar [options]="calendarOptions" (initialized)="onCalendarInit($event)"></angular2-fullcalendar>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you reproduce this in stackblitz it hard to figure out the requirement

Comment: @RahulSingh Sir updated, I want to know how to add modal popup correctly for  that event part  `events: [ { id: '1', resourceId: 'a', start: '2017-12-01',end: '2017-12-07',
       title: 'Mahesh'
      },  ],`

Comment: sir its hard to figure out , do you want to have the model open on selecting the date in the calendar ?

Comment: @RahulSingh yes, sir when I click on the event i want to know how to show modal popup,I m already do that in html, but i dont know how to do that 
 using Angular

Comment: can you please replicate this calendar in stacblitz i will add it up there

Comment: @RahulSingh Sir Im updated for one event my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161722/discussion-between-core114-and-rahul-singh).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with bootstrap, say ngx-bootstrap, modal.

Here's a link for using ngx-bootstrap modal: [ngx-bootstrap-how-to-open-a-modal-from-another-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46698126/ngx-bootstrap-how-to-open-a-modal-from-another-component)

You use `eventClick` to launch the modal:

```
eventClick(model: any) {
    // this is used to pass event data to modal component
    const initialState = { apptEvent: model.event};

    this.bsModalRef = 
         this.modalService.show(ModalComponent, 
            Object.assign({}, this.modalConfig, { class: 'modal-md', 
            initialState }));

    this.bsModalRef.content.onClose.subscribe(result => {
         // close the modal
         this.bsModalRef.hide();
    })

};
```

The `ModalComponent` will use the event data to render the view.