# ngx-bootstrap , Component Modal, The selector "modal-content" did not match any elements

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

I have `Angular 7`  `"ngx-bootstrap": "^3.1.4"` and `"bootstrap": "^4.3.1"`

Are these compatible at all?

I trying to open component in modal as this question: [ngx-bootstrap How to open a modal from another component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46698126/ngx-bootstrap-how-to-open-a-modal-from-another-component)

However I'm getting this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DialogBoxComponent -> BsModalRef]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[DialogBoxComponent -> BsModalRef]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for BsModalRef!
>   Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DialogBoxComponent -> BsModalRef]:

I have imported ngx in my module as:

```
        import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
    import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
    import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

    import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
    import { AppHeaderComponent } from './app-header/app-header.component';
    import { AppFooterComponent } from './app-footer/app-footer.component';
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { PoliciesComponent } from './policies/policies.component';
    import { AddComponent } from './add/add.component';
    import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
    import { ModalContentComponent } from './modal-content/modal-content.component';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent, AppHeaderComponent, AppFooterComponent, PoliciesComponent, AddComponent, ModalContentComponent],
      imports: [
        ModalModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule

      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent, ModalContentComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }



    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

    @Component({
      selector: 'modal-content',
      templateUrl: './modal-content.component.html',
    })

    export class ModalContentComponent {
      title: string;
      closeBtnName: string;
      list: any[] = [];

      constructor(public bsModalRef: BsModalRef) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.list.push('PROFIT!!!');
      }
    }

import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { PoliciesService } from './policies.service';
import { Policy } from 'src/models/policy';
import { Gender } from 'src/models/gender';
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { ModalContentComponent } from '../modal-content/modal-content.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-policies',
  templateUrl: './policies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./policies.component.scss']
})
export class PoliciesComponent implements OnInit {
  gender = Gender;
  policies: Policy[];
  bsModalRef: BsModalRef;

  constructor(private policiesService: PoliciesService, private modalService: BsModalService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.policiesService
      .getAll()
      .subscribe(p => this.policies = p);
  }

  deleteClicked(id: number) {
    this.policiesService
      .delete(id)
      .subscribe(() => this.deleteFrom(this.policies, id));
  }

  private deleteFrom(arr: Policy[], id: number) {
    arr.splice(arr.findIndex((p: Policy) => p.policyNumber === id), 1);
  }

  openModalWithComponent() {
    const initialState = {
      list: [
        'Open a modal with component',
        'Pass your data',
        'Do something else',
        '...'
      ],
      title: 'Modal with component'
    };
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ModalContentComponent, { initialState });
    this.bsModalRef.content.closeBtnName = 'Close';
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show where `BsModalRef` is being used?

Comment: @JasonWhite I solved my first issue, I don't know what was the issue. Now I have another issue: The selector "modal-content" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement

Answer (score 0):

I had an error where I added ModalContentComponent. 
It should be added as below to module:

```
providers: [],
  entryComponents: [ModalContentComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```